# Facebook chat plugin get sender URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat, prestashop

I found unclear on Facebook's documentation how to insert the referral code inside the "Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript" code that I already have on my website.
This is what I already have running well:

```
  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
{literal}<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>{/literal}

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="00000000000000"
 greeting_dialog_display="hide"
  logged_in_greeting="Hello!"
  logged_out_greeting="Bye!">
</div>
<!-- End your customer chat code -->
```

And this is the referral code that Facebook says on [THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals/) page:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "user_ref":"<USER_REF>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "referral": {
     "ref": "<REF_DATA_PASSED_IN_CODE>",
     "source": "CUSTOMER_CHAT_PLUGIN",
     "type": "OPEN_THREAD",
     "referer_uri": "<WEBSITE_URL>"
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Either put the value into `data-ref` on the `fb-customerchat` when you output that snippet of HTML, or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk#update_greeting_ref

Comment: This is the exact part where Facebook tells what to do, but don't know how to implement it in my code:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals/#customer-chat

Comment: Are you asking about the webhook part now? There a full section explaining that in great detail, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook